# package containerd.io >= 1.6.4 needed by docker-ce but package containerd.io already with version 1.6.9-3.1

Tags: docker, redhat, yum, rhel8

we want to install docker packages on our **RHEL 8.4** server (this is off line installation since machine not connected to network)

so we download the following rpm's from the site - https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/8/x86_64/stable/Packages/

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 34558068 Sep  6 14:41 containerd.io-1.6.9-3.1.el8.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3930488 Sep  6 14:42 docker-scan-plugin-0.9.0-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13710120 Sep  6 14:42 docker-buildx-plugin-0.11.2-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 25375804 Sep  6 14:42 docker-ce-24.0.6-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7514336 Sep  6 14:43 docker-ce-cli-24.0.6-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5119608 Sep  6 14:43 docker-ce-rootless-extras-24.0.6-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7370924 Sep  6 14:43 docker-compose-plugin-2.6.0-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
```

then we tried to install the rpm's as the following

```
yum localinstall docker-ce-24.0.6-1.el8.x86_64.rpm docker-scan-plugin-0.9.0-3.el8.x86_64.rpm  docker-buildx-plugin-0.11.2-1.el8.x86_64.rpm  docker-ce-cli-24.0.6-1.el8.x86_64.rpm  docker-ce-rootless-extras-24.0.6-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
Failed loading plugin "product-id": No module named 'subscription_manager.productid'
Failed loading plugin "subscription-manager": cannot import name 'injection'
Failed loading plugin "upload-profile": cannot import name 'packageprofilelib'
Last metadata expiration check: 2:49:54 ago on Wed 06 Sep 2023 12:21:52 PM UTC.
Error:
 Problem 1: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides containerd.io >= 1.6.4 needed by docker-ce-3:24.0.6-1.el8.x86_64
 Problem 2: package docker-ce-rootless-extras-24.0.6-1.el8.x86_64 requires docker-ce, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides containerd.io >= 1.6.4 needed by docker-ce-3:24.0.6-1.el8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

as we can see from above the exception is about :

```
 nothing provides containerd.io >= 1.6.4 needed by docker-ce-3:24.0.6-1.el8.x86_64
```

but one of our containerd.io rpm is already with version - `1.6.9-3.1`

so I not understand why rpm - `docker-ce-24.0.6-1.el8.x86_64.rpm` complained about this

any suggestion to solve this problem?